# java system properties vs spring boot application.properties vs maven properties

Tags: java, spring, maven

Java **system properties**, properties defined inside **application.properties** file and properties defined in **pom.xml** file, are they the same ?

1. What is different between all of these properties ?
2. Is it possible to reference one through the other (eg, pass system property from pom.xml file ...)
3. Are they all part of Java or JEE standard ? which one is ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the same.

Java system properties are pure Java. They are part of Java. Values can be set from the command line and within code with `System.getProperties.setProperty()`

Maven properties are in pom.xml with ‘<properties’>’<property’> tag. Maven is a build tool so these properties are used at build time.

Spring framework properties (application.properties or application.yaml). These properties are read at runtime, mostly during startup.  Standard properties are read by Spring classes, eg spring.data.source.url. They can also be accessed in code with @Value

You can get pom properties into application.properties with the following in the application.properties file:

```
foo.bar=@application.name@
```

You can get application.properties into system properties with the following in a class:

```
@Value(${foo.bar})
String applicationName;

System.getProperties.setProperty("application.name", applicationName)
```